# Import processing.video.* on Intellij

Tags: java, video, processing

I am trying to run a mp4 video in Java using Processing.

I'm trying to use Intellij IDEA, but when I try to `import processing.video.*` it doesn't find the video library.

Where can I find and how can I import this library?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Find the `.jar` files (and any other files) required by the library.
2. Add those files to your classpath.

You can find the library files in your Processing directory. For me mine are in `C:\Users\kevin\Documents\Processing\libraries\video\library`, but it's going to depend on your OS and where you installed Processing.

You can also build the library yourself from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/processing/processing-video).

Now that you have those files, you can add them to your classpath. Since you're using Intellij, the links in [Slaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916974/import-processing-video-on-intelij#comment94676819_53916974) should get you pretty far:

- [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051640/873165)
- [Working with libraries - Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html)